# Protractor Repeater Inside Element

Tags: javascript, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I want to access a repeater within another element:

[image]

If I have the following:

```
var dates = $('#provider_details_view').element.all(by.repeater('repeater name');
```

it doesn't work and says $(...).element.all is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Do the chaining correctly*, call `.all()` directly instead of `.element.all()`:

```
var dates = $('#provider_details_view').all(by.repeater('repeater name');
```

Comment: @rfodge and thanks to you, this inspired me to create a yet another eslint rule to catch this kind of problems statically: https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/36.